# cannot modify sshd_config as Root (centos)

Tags: centos, ssh, permissions

After looking through several threads on securing SSH on our server and have run into a little trouble when modifying sshd_config. I went through making the relevant changes and when I exit the file to save it I get a permission denied error. I am still fairly new to the linux server environment and any help in working around this will be greatly appreciated.

I first started by checking that I have RW on the file

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3176 Nov 16  2011 sshd_config
```

output of who

```
root     pts/0        2013-04-29 12:00
```

Output of lsattr

```
s---ia------- sshd_config
```

When I try to use chattr -V -ui /etc/ssh/sshd_config I get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/chattr: Permission denied
```

Comment: Is your filesystem where sshd_config is located writable? You can check it in "mount" command output

Comment: @KrzysztofKsiężyk `cat /proc/mounts` is better (because the real kernel's view) that `mount` (which just shows a file you could write everything into).

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/chattr` and `file /usr/bin/chattr`?

Answer (score 1):

please run below command to reset attributes of file:

> chattr -ais sshd_config

Now you will able to modify your file.